# Error with initialization of 2d arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c

So, I have declared a typedef as:

```
typedef float Matrix4[4][4];
```

when I try to Initialize it as:

```
void getXRotationMatrix(float theta, Matrix4 ans) {

    ans = { {0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1} };
}
```

it gives an error:

> too many initializer values

however, it works when I initialize it as:

```
void getXRotationMatrix(float theta, Matrix4 ans) {

    float a[4][4] = { {0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1} };
    ans = a;

}
```

It doesn't give any error. Can someone please explain?

Comment: `ans = ...` is *assignment* and not initialization. And you can't assign to arrays using brace-enclosed lists.

Answer (score 2):

> when I try to Initialize it as: ans = { {0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1} };

Note that

```
ans = { {0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1} };
```

is an **assignment** and not an initialization. On the other hand,

```
float a[4][4] = { {0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1} };
```

is an initialization and so works.

The correct way to initialize `ans` would be:

```
Matrix4 ans{ {0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1} };
```

Also note that array assignment is **not possible** in C++.

There is also the concept of **type decay** that you have to take care(into account) for `ans = a;`. In particular, both `ans` and `a` are actually pointers and so when you write

```
ans = a;
```

you're actually assigning one pointer to another instead of one array to another.

You can use a `std::vector` as follows:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<float>> Matrix4;
void getXRotationMatrix(float theta, Matrix4 ans) {

    ans = { {0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1} };

}
```

Comment: `ans = a;` "works", because `ans` is a pointer to the array on the call side, not the array itself. After the assignment `ans` points to `a`, but does not change anything on the call side array.

Comment: @mch Yes i know, i have added it at the end of my answer.

Comment: I suggest adding a word that a way to set `ans` in C is `memcpy(ans, a, sizeof a);`

Answer (score 2):

> Error with initialization of 2d arrays in C++
>
> when I try to Initialize it as:
>
> ```
> ans = { {0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1} };
> ```

Problem 1: That's not initialisation. That's assignment. Arrays cannot be assigned, but that's irrelevant due to next point.

Problem 2: `ans` is not an array. Function parameters are never arrays. Although you wrote it as an array, it has been adjusted to be a pointer to the element of the said array type. And the braced-init list that you provided is not a valid right hand argument for assigning a pointer.

> however, it works when I initialize it as:
>
> ans = a;

It becomes well-formed because `a` is a valid expression to assign to the pointer. The array will implicitly convert to a pointer to first element.

But the pointer is local to the function, so that function has no side-effects whatsoever.

---

I recommend returning instead of attempting to modify the parameter. Now, arrays cannot be returned in C++, but there is a simple solution: You can return class instances, and classes may contain array as a member. There is a class template for such array wrapper in the standard library. It's called `std::array`. Example:

```
std::array<float[4], 4>
getXRotationMatrix() {
    return {{
         {0,0,0,0},
         {1,1,1,1},
         {0,0,0,0},
         {1,1,1,1},
    }};
}
```

Comment: I am trying to return an array with your method but it's giving me the error:
C++ function returns incomplete type "std::array<float[4],4>"

Comment: @thecoderenroute Did you include the header that defines `std::array`?